# Unexpected behaviour of derived class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, overriding, derived-class

I have a simple program as follows:

```
class Foo {
    private final String str = getClass().getSimpleName();

    protected void print(){
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    private final String str = getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void print(){
        super.print();
        System.out.println(str);
    }   
}

class FooBarMain {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.print();

        Foo foobar = new Bar();
        foobar.print();

        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.print();
    }
}
```

output: 
Foo
Bar
Bar
Bar
Bar

Shouldn't the output as follows?
Foo
Foo
Bar
Foo
Bar

Looking at the output, it seems that `str` has been overridden in derived class. But, 
`str` is final and private. There is no way that it can be overridden. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that `str` is being overridden. It's just being calculated when you construct the object. Your `Bar` class has two different `str` values, each of which is determined when you initialize the object by using `getClass().getSimpleName();`.

Even though the `super.print()` in `Bar` is referencing the `str` in the `Foo` class, that value is still being initialized using the `getClass()` method of a `Bar` object.

Once you actually run the code, `getClass()` doesn't care that you wrote it inside of the `Foo` class declaration. All it knows is what the actual class of the object is when it evaluates.

From the docs of `getClass`

> Returns the **runtime class** of this Object. The returned Class object is the object that is locked by static synchronized methods of the represented class.

Since your method is not static, it is evaluated when the object is constructed, not when the class is declared. At that point in time, a `Bar` is a `Bar`, so in order to follow the contract it promises, `getClass` is required to return `Bar.class`.

Comment: ok..I just replaced getClass().getSimpleName() with another values and it works as expected. Can you explain in brief how this is done by getClass() ?

Comment: @NathanHughes and resueman thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 5):

It's simple, really: you use `getClass()` which means `this.getClass()`. If you instantiate `Bar`, then `getClass()` will return class `Bar` - whether it be called in `Foo` or in `Bar`: either way, the class is `Bar`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get the output you expected is just to do

```
class Foo {
    private final String str = "Foo";

    protected void print(){
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    private final String str = "Bar";

    @Override
    protected void print(){
        super.print();
        System.out.println(str);
    }   
}
```

`getClass()` does not do what you think. It does not return the class where the line `getClass` appears, it returns the actual runtime type of the instance. So if the object was instantiated using `new Bar()`, `getClass()` will *always* give you `Bar.class` even if the code appears in `Foo` and even if the compile-time type of the variable is `Foo` (as in your `Foo fooBar = new Bar();` example).

Comment: ya I did that. That works fine. I understood now. thanks

Answer (score -2):

The member str in Bar hides the one in Foo, so if you have a Bar object, it will always print "Bar".  It does not matter what type the variable is that holds the object handle, whether type is Foo or Bar, whenever you create a Bar, it is a Bar, whether you treat it as a Bar, Foo, or Object.

Comment: downvoted because this is mistaken, shadowing doesn't come into play, it's that getClass always returns the concrete class regardless of if it's called from Foo or from Bar.

Comment: yes, I agree, especially if the getClass().getName() was only done in base class. But if str was hard-coded to "Foo" and "Bar" appropriately, it still behave the same way, and this would be the reason.

Comment: the first sentence is still misleading, hiding has nothing to do with it.